# Div dragged when I click on the scrollbar - FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, firefox, draggable

I have a problem with a draggable directive on Firefox. Basecally I use an directive to make a div draggable but when I want to scroll by using scrollbar the div is moving so I can't scroll on the div.
This problem appears only when I use Firefox.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you make an example that we can look at? https://jsfiddle.net is a good place to do that.

Comment: You happen to solve this?